# IE css background issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, linear-gradients

Is the following correct since IE doesn't support "liner-gradient"?

```
    background: #f5f7f9; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f9 0%, #cdcdcd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f5f7f9), color-stop(100%,#cdcdcd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f9 0%,#cdcdcd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f9 0%,#cdcdcd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f9 0%,#cdcdcd 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f7f9 0%,#cdcdcd 100%); /* W3C */
    background:url(../img/backgrounds/form_bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
```

I am basically offering an image fallback.

This is not working in IE9 and below

Comment: Don't see why not, have you tested it?

Comment: You might want to add that last line (with the image in it) above your gradients, [like this](http://jsbin.com/uyOhEWi/2/).

Comment: This is not working in IE9 and below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put your fallback **first** in the cascade.  Example:

```
body {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/500/500) top center #cdcdcd no-repeat;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f9 0%, #cdcdcd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f5f7f9), color-stop(100%,#cdcdcd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f9 0%,#cdcdcd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f9 0%,#cdcdcd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7f9 0%,#cdcdcd 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f7f9 0%,#cdcdcd 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

Modern browsers consider the gradient to be a kind of background image. With the fallback first, browsers that can understand the fallback will use it, and browsers that can understand the other specifications will override the fallback with the gradients. For example, IE7 will only understand the background image, and ignore the gradients. Chrome will do the background image, and then override the background image with the `linear-gradient`.

Second, `-ms-linear-gradient` support begins in IE10; it's not supported by IE9, so that's why it doesn't work in IE9 and below.

You can use filters for IE9 through 6. Example:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3838', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

If you use a filter, you will also need to disable the fallback image, since IE 6 - 9 don't replace background images with filters. I prefer to do this with [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html):

```
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 9)]>
<style type="text/css">
body { background-image: none; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Note that the conditional comments are HTML.

Last, most sites probably don't need the `-moz`, `-webkit` or `-o` prefixes; each of them has [supported the standard `linear-gradient` for a while](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients).